# Unlock bitlocker drive using udisksctl > error

Tags: encryption, udisks

I try to use `udisksctl` to unlock a bitlocked drive. The key is stored in keyhorse, and I can get it using `secret-tool`.

The command I tried is:

```
udisksctl unlock -b /dev/nvme0n1p3 --key-file <(secret-tool lookup gvfs-luks-uuid ef619c42-3278-40b2-9ac0-7d4011283728)
```

But I get:

```
Error unlocking /dev/nvme0n1p3: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.Failed: No key available to unlock device /dev/nvme0n1p3
```

However I checked that `secret-tool lookup ...` really provides the correct key. If I do not put it under the argument `--key-file`, but instead type it when the prompt asks for it, then it works! But if I put the key in a file, it does not work, with the same error above.

**Why do I get this error?**

EDIT: I just found out that this option is not supported for bitlocker: https://github.com/storaged-project/udisks/issues/1252.
I guess my question is now: is there a workaround? How does `nautilus` unlock the drive, if not with `udisksctl`?

EDIT: [a fix has been recently pushed](https://github.com/vojtechtrefny/storaged/commit/bcea14ea997af2d4cda159b1c1cce37459508173)